# Family of equicontinuous function on a compact metric space $X$ to a metric space $Y$ is uniformly equicontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, equicontinuity, arzela-ascoli

If $X$, $Y$ are metric spaces, $X$ is compact and $F\subseteq Y^X$ if

$F$ is equicontinuous at any point $x$ i.e.

for all $x\in X$ and $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that

when $d_X(x,x^\prime)<\delta$ then $d_Y(f(x),f(x^\prime))<\varepsilon$ for all $f\in F$.

Then since $X$ is compact $F$ is uniformly equicontinuous i.e.

for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that

when $d_X(x,x^\prime)<\delta$ then $d_Y(f(x),f(x^\prime))<\varepsilon$ for all $f\in F$.

So actually in the Arzela Ascoli theorem one could alter the uniform equicontinuity condition to equicontinuity at any point $x\in X$?

Comment: yes............

Comment: Indeed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Compact_metric_spaces_and_compact_Hausdorff_spaces